# How do I split a string in zig by a specific character?

Tags: split, zig

I have a simple sentence in a string. I want to print each word on a new line or otherwise just do some calculation on each word?

Is there something similar to python's `"Hello World".split()` in zig? Something like this:

```
var arr = std.strings.split("Hello world");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is the simplest way I found

```
const std = @import("std");

pub fn main() !void {
    var it = std.mem.split(u8, "Hello World", " ");
    while (it.next()) |x| {
        std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{x});
    }
}
```

It looks like splitting is implemented in the standard `mem` module. `.split` returns `SplitIterator` which is a structure with a `.next()` method. When `.next()` returns null, the while stops. This is a common pattern in zig:

https://ziglearn.org/chapter-2/#iterators